# How shall I understand the definitions of `let` expression?

Tags: logic, programming-languages, lambda-calculus

`let` as used in programming languages is defined in lambda calculus as per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let_expression#Let_definition_defined_from_lambda_calculus

> The simple, non recursive let expression was defined as being
>   syntactic sugar for the lambda abstraction applied to a term. In that
>   definition,
>
> $$ ( let_s ⁡\quad x = y \quad in \quad⁡ z ) ≡ ( λ x . z )   y $$

`let` also has another definition in terms of logic, per
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let_expression#Let_definition_in_mathematics says

> In mathematics the let expression is described as the conjunction of
>   expressions. In functional languages the let expression is also used
>   to limit scope. In mathematics scope is described by quantifiers. The
>   let expression is a conjunction within an existential quantifier.
>
> $$   ( ∃ x E ∧ F ) ⟺ let ⁡\quad x : E \quad in \quad⁡ F  $$
>
> where $E$ and $F$ are of type Boolean.
>
> The let expression allows **the substitution** to be applied to another
>   expression. This substitution may be applied within a restricted
>   scope, to a sub expression.

In the definition $ ∃ x E ∧ F $ by logic,

- Are $E$ and $F$ both propositions?
- what does $ ∃ x E ∧ F $ mean? Does it mean $ ( ∃ x E) ∧ F$ or $ ∃ x (E ∧ F )$?
- what "substitution" does  $ ∃ x E ∧ F $ allow?
- how does  $ ∃ x E ∧ F $ relate to the first definition $( λ x . z )   y$ ?

Does language C have similar construct to `let`?

Thanks.

Comment: Existential quantifier has higher precendance than AND operator, so it must mean $(\exists x E) \land F$. I’m not familiar with this “let equivalence”, looks strange

Comment: @SandroLovnički the text says "conjunction within an existential quantifier". I think it can only mean that the conjunction is under the quantifier's scope. Also this is in line with usual notation, when quantifier's scope extends to the right as far as possible. (Also that must be the reason for parenthesis around left-hand side expression.)